# Object Recognition with SIFT Features

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, object-recognition

I am working on simple object recogniton of 3 types of objects namely:
1. Book
2. Cups
3. Balls

I have training image of 50 for each samples and a test image of 20 for each samples. All my pocessing and classification is performed very well and there is not a problem with that.

But my problem is the last part of the project where i should draw a rectangular box around the detected object in the test image. Uptil now i checked my classification and it works well with bayes classification. My question is, that i have 50 test image, how i select the best match from the 50 samples to be able to draw the bounding box without object occulsion or perhaps enclosing larger area. 
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html
The link shows one to one object matching using surf and what  i am trying to do in my work is using similar algorithm, i calculate all the keypoints of same type sample and perform match. But the problem is i dont know which image to select to be able to perform the match.

Please if you can provide me with some hints it will be extremely helpful
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "training image of 50 for each samples" and "a test image of 20 for each samples"? Perhaps you can give an example or post some images to better illustrate your problem. As it is your English is pretty hard to decipher.

Comment: i have models (100 x 150) of cups for example and than i have a test image (640 x 480) with cup on the table. my problem is how i determine from the sample of training image the best match image to be able to draw the correct bounding box around the cup in the test image

Comment: Why not SIFT or SURF with all of the relevant training images and choose the best match?

Comment: Actually my question is how I select the best matching image. Some images has more keypoints but are not best match. I am just stuck here that how i select the best match.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to check the number of inliers after computing a homography between the query and the test image. Take a look at [this OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html). If the inlier set agreeing with the homography is large, then it indicates a good match between the two images. This may or may not work for your problem, but it is definitely worth a shot.